# R GLM: Modify coefficients of an existing glm model

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, glm, coefficients

I have been trying to adjust the coefficients of an existing glm model but the predictions don't seem to change. The idea is to enhance an existing logistic model by incorporating 'qualitative' parameters in the quantitative coefficients (see 'adj model' block). I replicated the problem below.

I really appreciate any. Thank you!

```
set.seed(100)

#create sim data (correlated)
input_size <- 200
scale <- 10000
y_var = sample(0:1, input_size, replace = TRUE)
input_data <- cbind.data.frame(y_var, x1 = sample(1:1000, input_size, replace = TRUE) + (y_var*200), x2 = sample(1:50, input_size, replace = TRUE) - (y_var*30))
cor(input_data)

#build log-reg model
reg1 <- glm(input_data$y ~ input_data$x1 + input_data$x2, data = input_data, family = "binomial")
reg1$coefficients

#test log-reg model
input_test <- cbind.data.frame(x1 = sample(1:1000, input_size, replace = TRUE) + (y_var*400), x2 = sample(1:50, input_size, replace = TRUE) - (y_var*10))
y_predict <- predict(reg1, input_test, type="response")

#adjust log-reg model
adj_coeff <- round(c(intercept = reg1$coefficients[1], x1 = reg1$coefficients[2] * 3, x2 = -reg1$coefficients[3] * 0.5), 4)
reg2 <- reg1
reg2$coefficients <- as.numeric(adj_coeff)
reg2$coefficients

#visualize predication of the log-reg models
y2_predict <- predict(reg1, input_test, type="response")
plot(y_predict, type = "p", lwd = 2)
lines(y2_predict, type = "p", pch = 3, col = "orange")
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is that `predict` doesn't use `$coefficients` but relies instead on some other part of the model object from which `$coefficients` is also derived for its computations, but that's just a hunch.

Comment: @ulfelder thanks for the hint! I will look into that.

Comment: y2_predict <- predict(reg1, input_test, type="response") ; if you use the first model to predict, it's no surprise you can the same results. just consider using functions the next time round..